# After changing the IP in of CouchBase server how to get back the database

Tags: node.js, ip, ip-address, couchbase

**Scenario**: 
Installed the CouchBase Server and faced the following issue:
`IP address seems to have changed. Unable to listen on 'ns_1@169.254.20.219'`

Got it resolved by following the steps on couchbase docs [Handling IP Addresses](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip.html)
So, my file `C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\service_register.bat`

```
set NS_BIN=%~dp0
set NS_ROOT=%NS_BIN%..
set NS_ERTS=%NS_BIN%erlang\erts-5.8.3\bin

pushd "%NS_ROOT%"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('cmd /q/c "type bin\ipaddr.out"') do set IP_ADDR=%%a

set NS_NAME=ns_1@192.168.3.53
if not "%1"=="" set NS_NAME=%1

pushd "%NS_ROOT%"
"%NS_ERTS%\erlsrv.exe" add CouchbaseServer -stopaction "ns_bootstrap:stop()." -name %NS_NAME% -InternalServiceName CouchbaseServer -onfail restart -workdir "%NS_ROOT%" -args "+A 16 -setcookie nocookie -ns_server config_path \\\".\\etc\\couchbase\\static_config\\\" -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 21100 inet_dist_listen_max 21299 -run ns_bootstrap override_resolver -ns_server restart_script \\\".\\bin\\service_reregister.bat\\\" -- %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"
popd

set serviceId=""
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('sc GetKeyName CouchbaseServer') do set serviceId=%%s
sc description %serviceId% "Couchbase Server Service"
```

I started using it with Node.JS and was able to store data, etc..

**Issue**: My IP address is dynamic and If I follow the same steps to fix the same issue i.e. `'IP address seems to have changed. Unable to listen on 'ns_1@192.168.3.53'` and change it to new IP address say `192.168.3.58`. Then I am able to fix the issue. But I am losing all configs. So, the server starts asking all setup (from creating admin's account), ultimately my database and data is getting lost.

**Question**: How can I get back my old database when IP address was `192.168.3.53` and why it dumps all the things when IP is changed in `service_register.bat`?

Advance Thanks

Comment: I follow the advice of using the HostName rather than the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested but procedure here: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-backup-restore-restore.html#couchbase-backup-restore-prevstate-same should allow you to get back your data.

I.e. when node detects it's out of cluster, it will reset itself. But it will leave data files intact *until* you try to set it up again or join it to cluster. It was done exactly for cases when failover was accidental or for issues like yours.